# API Authentication issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-api

I'm working on creating APIs for the first time using laravel, please excuse me if I mention anything incorrect and let me know how to correct it.

I have followed this article to create API authentication, https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

now I'm able to register the user and I'm getting api-token as per the blog, but when I try to login with the existing user, I'm getting the below error

```
    "message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Auth\\GenericUser::generateToken()",
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController.php",
    "line": 61,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "login",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 254,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 197,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 693,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 127,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 695,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 670,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 625,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 166,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myProject\\server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm the same error for logout as well.

I'm attaching my login controller and RegisterController, Please let me know if you need more details and help me to solve this issue

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {

            $user = $this->guard()->user();
            //$user = Auth::user();
            //get user from db and return it to $user
            $user->generateToken();
            return response()->json([
                'data' => $user->toArray(),
            ]);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

        if ($user) {
            $user->api_token = null;
            $user->save();
        }

        return response()->json(['data' => $user + ': User logged out.'], 200);
    }

}
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->generateToken();

        return response()->json(['data' => $user->toArray()], 201);
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't completed the tutorial. Jump to the section that says `In the section above, we used a method on the User model to generate the token. This is useful so that we only have a single way of generating the tokens. Add the following method to your User model:`

Comment: I have already done it, there was some other issue, I tried creating a new project again which worked fine. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.